# App crashes on click of Back button in iPhone

Tags: iphone, ipad, uiwebview, nsurlconnection, back-button

I am new to iPhone,

I am currently developing an iPhone app and in which i have implement the ability to download file from the url. I have created the UIWebView, when users clicks on download link in the `webview`, download will start and i am saving that file to a specified folder in the documents directory, this all things are working fine in my `Second View`..

but after this when i press a back button for navigating to a my `First view`, my app gets crashed... shows `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
        //Doing some operation and it works fine...
           NSLog(@"viewWillAppear in First View.......");
    }

-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    NSLog(@"viewDidAppear in First View.......");
}
```

I am able to see above `Log` When i hit back button but my app crashes after 1 or half second.

Here is my code in `Second View`,

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{
    [receivedData setLength:0];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data1
{
    [receivedData appendData:data1];
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    NSLog(@"Succeeded! Received %d bytes of data",[receivedData length]);

    DirPath=[self applicationDocumentsDirectory];

     NSLog(@"DirPath=%@",DirPath);
    [receivedData writeToFile:DirPath atomically:YES];

    UIAlertView* Alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Download Complete !"
                                                         message:nil delegate:nil 
                                               cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                               otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [Alert show];
    [Alert release];


    // release the connection, and the data object
    [connection release];
    [receivedData release];
}


- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error1
{
    [connection release];
    [receivedData release];

    // inform the user
    NSLog(@"Connection failed! Error - %@ %@",
          [error1 localizedDescription],
          [[error1 userInfo] objectForKey:NSURLErrorFailingURLStringErrorKey]);
}

- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView*)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest*)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {

    url = [request URL];

    //CAPTURE USER LINK-CLICK.

            DirPath=[self applicationDocumentsDirectory];

            Durl=[[url absoluteString]copy];

            //Checking for Duplicate .FILE at downloaded path....

            BOOL success =[[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:path];
            lastPath=[[url lastPathComponent] copy];

            if (success) //if duplicate file found...
            {
                UIAlertView* Alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"This FILE is already present in Library."
                                                                     message:@"Do you want to Downlaod again ?" delegate:self 
                                                           cancelButtonTitle:nil
                                                           otherButtonTitles:@"Yes",@"No",nil];
                [Alert show];
                [Alert release];

            }
            else  //if duplicate file not found directly start download...
            {
                // Create the request.
                NSURLRequest *theRequest=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:Durl]
                                                          cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy
                                                      timeoutInterval:60.0];

                // create the connection with the request and start loading the data
                NSURLConnection *theConnection=[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self];
                if (theConnection) {
                    // Create the NSMutableData to hold the received data.
                    receivedData = [[NSMutableData data] retain];
                } else {
                    NSLog(@"Inform the user that the connection failed."); 
                }

    return YES;   
}

- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{ 
    if (buttonIndex == 0) 
    {        
        // Create the request.
        NSURLRequest *theRequest1=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:Durl]
                                                  cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy
                                              timeoutInterval:60.0];

        // create the connection with the request and start loading the data
        NSURLConnection *theConnection1=[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest1 delegate:self];
        if (theConnection1) {
            // Create the NSMutableData to hold the received data.
            receivedData = [[NSMutableData data] retain];
        } else {
            NSLog(@"Inform the user that the connection failed."); 
        }

    }
    else
    {[alertView dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:1 animated:TRUE];}
}

- (void)webView:(UIWebView *)webview didFailLoadWithError:(NSError *)error1 {

    NSLog(@"didFailLoadWithError: %@; stillLoading:%@", error1,(webview.loading?@"NO":@"YES"));
}
```

My Log shows: `didFailLoadWithError: Error Domain=WebKitErrorDomain Code=102 "Frame load interrupted" UserInfo=0x6b34910 {NSErrorFailingURLKey=MY_URL, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=MY_URL, NSLocalizedDescription=Frame load interrupted}; stillLoading:YES`

`DirPath=/Users/krunal/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/5.0/Applications/FCDDDE83-A9B3-4C14-A56C-E8C5FCE7F5C4/Documents/DownloadedFile.epub`

**Any help will be appriciated.**

Comment: i am not sure but please try to comment "[connection release];" code

Comment: A good practice for releasing instance variables is to set them `nil` after you're releasing them and plan to not use them anymore. That way many `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` errors by accidentally accessing the ivar after the release can be prevented.

Comment: @Ramshad: i tried but still crashes.

Comment: You should try web view delegate to nil when your back button click. Yourwebview.delegate = nil; in dealloc method

Comment: i wrote `webview.delegate=nil` in `dealloc` method but still crashes.

Comment: try it in `viewWillDisappear:` and if there is a cancel request method use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your are releasing wrong things... Consider this,

```
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error1
```

no need to release connection, receivedData

at dealloc block, add this code

```
- (void) dealloc
  {
      if (theConnection)
      { 
           [theConnection release], theConnection = nil;
      }

      if (receivedData)
      { 
           [receivedData release], receivedData = nil;
      }
  }
```

add if you are using same webView to create multiple connection, then add

```
if (theConnection)
{ 
      [theConnection release], theConnection = nil;
}

if (receivedData)
{ 
     receivedData release], receivedData = nil;
}
```

before allocating URLConnection and NsMutableData, thats a measure to stop memory leaks. And better to have a activity spinner until event is done.

Comment: what is the difference between the two block of code ? and where should i write second block of code ? if i am creating multiple connection.

Comment: 2nd block of code add it when you allocate theConnection, receivedData i.e, inside shouldStartLoadWithRequest and clickedButtonAtIndex

Answer (score 1):

First of all, the things you are trying to do here, you shouldn't be doing from a view. Code where you are communication with network services is better off in the Model classes, not in a view:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/CocoaDesignPatterns/CocoaDesignPatterns.html

Now you can end up in situations where the connection is calling delegate methods you have implemented in your view, but your view has already been released, as you clicked the back button.

Also, you don't maintain a pointer to the NSURLConnection instance you create in the webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest: method. Instead, you rely on the connectionDidFinishLoading: method being called to release the connection object again. This way you are never sure IF you are releasing it, or if you are maybe over-releasing it, if the method is called multiple times.

Use an instance variable in your view class to hold a pointer to the connection object, so you can release it when necessary (when you are not using it anymore, or when the view is going away). Make sure you also cancel the query before removing the view ([connection cancel]).

Comment: As you suggested, i declared NSURLConnection to global variable, and releasing it in `dealloc` method but app still crashes.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this in the secondView Controller class

```
- (void)viewWillDisappear
{
    if ([webView isLoading])
        [webView stopLoading];

    [webView setDelegate:nil];
}
```

Or add this in the back button action of the secondView

Answer (score 0):

In dealloc method of your first view in which WebView is added set delegate of webView = nil.
Some time this can be the reason of crash.

Comment: i tried `webView = nil` in dealloc method i also wrote `[theConnection release];
    theConnection=nil;
    [theRequest release];
    theRequest=nil;` but still app crashes..

Comment: I said to set delegate property of your webView object to nil.

Answer (score 0):

Do two things:

1. Where ever you are releasing connection and data (receivedData), set it to nil.
2. In your dealloc method, [webView stopLoading] before releasing webView.